# Experiencing a problem with attaching armature to models

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

So I'm making a game in Unity that requires custom 3D models and after finally figuring out the basics, I've run into a problem that I have never been able to solve, even after watching several tutorial, videos and guides and asking around.

Basically I've made a model out of several objects and the only way I can attach the armature to the model is by setting the parent to the object and before I figured this out, I watched every tutorial and video that showed people being able to select the armature, then the object, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select *Armature Deform > With Automatic Weights* to deform the character and it's always worked.

Every time I try this though, I get a warning sign at the top of blender that says: "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" And none of the armature attaches to the mesh. So the only method I've been able to use that successfully attaches the armature to the model is by attaching each bone to each part of the model(head, neck, bicep, forearm, etc)

Now I've made a model from 1 object and the attach bone to object clearly isn't an option as the whole thing spins when I try to rotate the neck to move the head.

I'm very new to blender and this issue is driving me crazy as everyone seems to make this work by using the automatic weights but for some reason mine just doesn't work.

I'm using blender 2.74 and I would greatly appreciate any help from anyone since I keep hitting this brick wall.

This is what the model I made of several objects looks like that I've been able to rig via bone to object:
http://sta.sh/02ek0lcmsdys

And this is the model I made as one object:
http://sta.sh/01gl7whz17je

I'm very new here and I signed up so I can get help with this issue because I seriously just can't get past it :(

Comment: that can be doubled vertices or others... hard to know without the model itself

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Okay, do I upload it then give you a link?

Comment: I'll send you a link to your youtube account since I'm not comfortable giving this model to the public.

Comment: @CraftyMaelyss Tried everything I could think of. No luck. Sorry.

Comment: @Shady Puck it's okay, I had to remake the model into separate pieces to rig it but I'll try to make something really simple and see if that helps P: